# How to add a class to the <body> for each language?

Tags: wordpress, class, localization

I want to add a specific class to the `<body>` when I switch languages with WPML. I am using English and German right now, so my goal is to get `<body class="en">` or `<body class="de">`  due to the switched on language. How can I manage that?

Comment: I think I will be using qTranslate for now since it gives me more abilities to fix the translations myself within my theme. If you got an answer to the question though please share it for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE. It's documented here:
http://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/

Something like this would work:

```
<body class="<?php echo(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) ?>">
```

Comment: For me this only works on the original language (english in this case), doesn't add anything on other translations.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me by adding it to my theme's functions.php file:

```
// WPML - Add language class to body element
function append_language_class($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'lang-' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'append_language_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress using q-translate I used this code

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'en') {
        $classes[] = 'eng';
    }
    elseif (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'ar') {
        $classes[] = 'arbic';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```